# разница между элементами списка и другого списка, являющегося значением словаря

Tags: list, python-3.6, словари

Здравствуйте, есть функция, часть которой представлена внизу, которая должна вычислять разницу между элементами списка g и списками, являющимися значениями словаря ang, и выводить output в виде:

```
{'linear':[разница],'bent':[разница]}
```

сам код:

```
   g = [132]
   ang = {'linear':[180],'bent':[120]}
        for k in ang:
                for i in g:
                        for x in ang[k]:
                               dict = {k: round(100*sum([abs(i-x)])/sum(g)) for k,ang[k] in ang.items()}
                               return(dict)
```

однако печатается только это:

```
{'linear':[36],'bent':[36]}
```

хотя правильным бы считался ответ:

```
{'linear':[36],'bent':[9]}
```

то есть считается только для linear, а для bent нет

во всех случаях число элементов g и число элементов в списках словаря одинаково

Comment: какой правильный ответ? Явно приведите ожидаемый ответ и словами опишите как этот ответ из представленных значений `g`, `ang` получается. Не используйте сломанный код в качестве спецификации задачи.

Comment: по какому именно алгоритму вы из 132, 180, 120 получаете 36, 9?

Comment: 36 = 100*(132-180)/(132)   9 =100*(132-120)/(120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вы похоже ищете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817649/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f#comment1300028_817649) относительную разницу в процентах:

```
def rel_err_pct(a, b):
    return round(100 * abs(a - b) / b)
```

Применив это у функцию к элементам списков, являющимися значениями в словаре:

```
result = {key: list(map(rel_err_pct, g, lst)) for key, lst in ang.items()}
```